# How to calculate the value from selections?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

Maybe an inappropriate question, but couldn't find a place to ask.

The problem: I have 3 numbers on html page (1.5, 2.5, -3.5).
I want to select each of them with my mouse (double click), and get the result of calculation in a clipboard (in this example 0.5).

Is it possible to do?

Comment: There is an event for db click : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/dblclick_event
If you put the numbers inside a dom element then you can attach a dbclick event to this element.

There is also a Clipboard API : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is definitely possible.

When the numbers are clicked, which are `<button>` in my example, it will add the class `selected` to the button clicked, to indicate that the number is selected, or remove it depending on the presence of the class `selected`.

After updating the class, it will call the function `calculateSum()`, which will select all the elements with the class `selected` and add the `innerText`, which are the selected numbers in this case, of them together.

Lastly, the `result` will be passed to the function `renderUpdate()` to visualize the updates.

```js
const selectableNumbers = document.querySelectorAll('.numbers')
selectableNumbers.forEach(n => {
  n.addEventListener('dblclick', e => {
    if (n.classList.contains('selected')) {
      n.classList.remove('selected')
    } else {
      n.classList.add('selected')
    }
    calculateSum()
  })
})

function calculateSum() {
  let result = 0
  const selectedNumbers = document.querySelectorAll('.selected')
  selectedNumbers.forEach(n => {
    result += parseFloat(n.innerText)
  })
  renderUpdate(result)
}

function renderUpdate(result) {
  const resultOutput = document.querySelector('.spanResult')
  resultOutput.innerText = `Sum: ${result.toString()}`
}
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="numbers">1.5</button>
<button class="numbers">2.5</button>
<button class="numbers">-3.5</button>
<span class="spanResult">Sum: 0</span>
```

For clipboard: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30810322/16491678

Hope this helps!